# Url rules for module are not working

Tags: yii2

this part of `yii2` configuration is kind of tricky, so i would really appreciate if anyone tells me the proper way to do it and why what i have tried is wrong..

i have a module called `Admin`, this module has few controllers and of course it takes the main layout for the view structures so all the links generated in the layout are available in the module as well, all seems nice but one thing, if the links are rendered in the module, all of them will have the module route in all these links.. i need them to be routed outside the module..

all the links i need them to be routed outside of the module have this pattern:
`<controller>/<action>`
while the module has this pattern: 
`admin/<controller>/<action>`

so far i have tried adding an `Url` rule in the config like this:

```
'rules'=>[
    '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
    //Also tried this: admin/<controller\w+>/<action:\w+>
]
```

but all of the links are still being generated in the same way.. when links are in generated in the module, they all have this pattern: `admin/<controller>/<action>` when they are just supposed to be something like this: `@root/<controller>/<action>`

Comment: Try by creating absulute Url using.. `Yii::$app->request->createAbsoluteUrl('module/controller/action');`

Comment: @DoubleH this would make the php code much larger than already is, there are more than 10 links rendered in a navbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you still have the default url rules, your urls should start with a leading slash e.g `/site/about` instead of `site/about`. From the docs for [Url::toRoute()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#toRoute%28%29-detail) :

> A route may be either absolute or relative. An absolute route has a leading slash (e.g. `/site/index`), while a relative route has none (e.g. `site/index` or `index`)
>
> ...
>
> If the route has no leading slash (e.g. `site/index`), it is considered to be a route relative to the current module and will be prepended with the module's `uniqueId`.

Comment: Does that work for Yii2? Double slashes aren't mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Sorry i was wrong this is really something from yii1. Never searched the docs regarding this change and it was also working with two slashes. Therefore i deleted my comment to not spreading wrong information.

Comment: i have made this change and looks like it works, although i need to understand completely the rules

Answer (score 0):

Example for custom rules from a personal proyect:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,

            'rules' => array(
                'register' => 'user/registration/register',
                'login' => 'user/security/login',
                'logout' => 'user/security/logout',
                'home' => 'site/index',

                'support' => 'contact/submit',
                'faq' => 'site/faq',

                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ],
```

This goes to the main config file in your app.